# AdMob ad stopped showing in one app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have setup Admob in my app correctly and it was working earlier but now it stopped showing ads and gives flowing error:

```
09-25 23:39:26.919: I/Ads(22050): App index is not enabled
09-25 23:39:30.432: E/Ads(28874): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-25 23:39:30.442: E/Ads(28874): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-25 23:39:30.442: I/Ads(28874): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
09-25 23:39:30.472: I/Ads(28874): Ad finished loading.
```

Whats strange is it starts showing ads if i change the package name of my app, is there anyone facing same problem or any solution of my problem?

I used following unit ad id:

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

which is provided in instructions to get test ads

Following is my mainActivity.java code:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

please give me solution to this problem...

Following is Manifest.xml cod for admob:

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Comment: What about your manifest file??

Comment: Maybe this can be your answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/HI9zQ0dfGHc

Comment: @GmloMalo updated my question with manifest cod

Answer (score 1):

> Whats strange is it starts showing ads if i change the package name of my app

Usually this means that your application has been suspended by AdMob for some reason. I would first recommend checking that your AdMob account is in good standing.

Comment: I am new to this, I have onlly one banner ad and my account looks fine, I didn't get any warning either, as u said my app may be suspended can you tell me in which conditions my app could be suspended? I have read all the instructions and FAQs there but I couldn't figure out what can cause suspension of my app!

Comment: If you app has been suspended you must have receive an email with the reason. One reason could be you have no use test ads instead real ads to test while debuggin